# Getting error while executing pslist remotely on a windows machine

Tags: windows, cygwin, remote-access, remote-server, tasklist

Getting the following error on windows when running pslist from 1 machine to access the process information of other machine:

```
!
check Process performance object not found on \\noivw-frm2k2208
check Run Exctrlst from the Windows Resource Kit to repair the performance counters.
calling C:/PsTools1.12/pslist.exe  \\\\noivw-frm2k2208  11012
procinfo for 11012 is Process performance object not found on \\noivw-frm2k2208
Run Exctrlst from the Windows Resource Kit to repair the performance counters.
```

Not sure what is causing this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: does not look like a cygwin issue.

Comment: @DougHenderson, what could be the issue? What shall be done?